# Refresh mongodb collection structure through python mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm writing a simple Flask app, with the sole purpose to learn Python and MongoDB.

I've managed to reach to the point where all the collections are defined, and CRUD operations work in general. Now, one thing that I really want to understand, is how to refresh the collection, after updating its structure. For example, say that I have the following `model`:

## user.py

```
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    email            = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    password         = db.StringField(required=True)
    active           = db.BooleanField()

    first_name       = db.StringField(max_length=64, required=True)
    last_name        = db.StringField(max_length=64, required=True)

    registered_at    = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    confirmed        = db.BooleanField()
    confirmed_at     = db.DateTimeField()

    last_login_at    = db.DateTimeField()
    current_login_at = db.DateTimeField()
    last_login_ip    = db.StringField(max_length=45)
    current_login_ip = db.StringField(max_length=45)
    login_count      = db.IntField()

    companies        = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Company'), default=[])
    roles            = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Role), default=[])

    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {'fields': ['email'], 'unique': True}
        ]
    }
```

Now, I already have entries in my `user` collection, but I want to change `companies` to:

```
company = db.ReferenceField('Company')
```

### How can I refresh the collection's structure, without having to bring the whole database down?

I do have a `manage.py` script that helps me and also provides a shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.script.commands import Shell

from app import factory

app = factory.create_app()

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("shell", Shell(use_ipython=True))

# manager.add_command('run_tests', RunTests())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

and I have tried a couple of commands, from information that I could recompile and out of my basic knowledge:

```
>>> from app.models import db, User
>>> import mongoengine
>>> mongoengine.Document(User)
      field = iter(self._fields_ordered)
      AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute '_fields_ordered'
>>> mongoengine.Document(User).modify() # well, same result as above
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

### Update

I am asking all of this, because I have updated my `user.py` to match my new requests, but anytime I interact with the db its self, since the table's structure was not refreshed, I get the following error:

> FieldDoesNotExist: The field 'companies' does not exist on the
>   document 'User', referer: http://local.faqcolab.com/company

Comment: MongoDB collections don't have a structure the way a relational database does. You can freely add new fields to documents any time you want. You can even have different fields on documents in a collection.

Comment: @dim I was expecting it to be that way, but it seems that is not. As I have mentioned in my Update, table's structure remains the same after updating the model its self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is easier then I expected:

```
db.getCollection('user').update(
    // query 
    {},

    // update 
    {
        $rename: {
            'companies': 'company'
        }
    },

    // options 
    {
        "multi" : true,  // update all documents
        "upsert" : false  // insert a new document, if no existing document match the query 
    }
);
```

Explanation for each of the `{}`:

- First is empty because I want to update all documents in `user` collection.
- Second contains [`$rename`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) which is the invoking action to rename the fields I want.
- Last contains aditional settings for the query to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

> I have updated my `user.py` to match my new requests, but anytime I interact with the db its self, since the table's structure was not refreshed, I get the following error

MongoDB does not have a "table structure" like relational databases do. After a document has been inserted, you can't change it's schema by changing the document model.

I don't want to sound like I'm telling you that the answer is to use different tools, but seeing things like `db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Company'))` makes me think you'd be much better off with a relational database (Postgres is well supported in the Flask ecosystem).

Mongo works best for storing schema-less documents (you don't know before hand how your data is structured, or it varies significantly between documents). Unless you have data like that, it's worth looking at other options. Especially since you're just getting started with Python and Flask, there's no point in making things harder than they are.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion... but I'm using MongoDB for learning purposes. I've found some ways of altering a Collection's structure.